# Is there way to fill some object in middleware, for its usage in services

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have an middleware which checks that some parameters in request's header are correct, and I check that there is one entity in db associated with one parameter from header (e.g `foo`).

But after this I need to get that entity again for getting some properties (e.g `fooEntity.bar`)

Is there way to set some object like `{ entity : fooEntity}` in middleware to di and resolve that object in services?
I want to reduce db calls

this is example of app

````
public class SomeMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ISomeService _someService;

    public SomeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ISomeService someService)
    {
        _next = next;
        _someService = someService;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var foo = RequestHeaderExtractor.GetValue(context.Request, Constants.FooName); // just getting value from header
        var baz = RequestHeaderExtractor.GetValue(context.Request, Constants.BazName);

        await _someService.Assert(foo);
        await _next(context);
    }
}

public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public AuthenticationService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public async Task Assert(string foo)
    {
        using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();

        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<Context>();

        var fooEntity = await context
            .Foo
            .Include(x => x.Bar)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Foo == foo);

        if (fooEntity?.Bar == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(fooEntity.Bar.Something))
        {
            throw new Exception("111 alarm");
        }
    }
}

// this is fooEntity.Bar.Something consumer
public class SomeHttpClient : ISomeHttpClient
{
   private readonly HttpClient _client;

   public SomeHttpClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IRequestInformationService requestInformationService)
   {
       _client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

       var something = requestInformationService.GetSomethingFromBar(); // getting FooEntity.Bar.Something

       var baseUri = new Uri(something);

       _client.BaseAddress = baseUri;

       // others setting
   }
}

public class RequestInformationService : IRequestInformationService
{
   private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;
   private readonly DataContext _dataContext;

   public RequestInformationService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, DataContext dataContext)
   {
       _dataContext = dataContext;
       _httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
   }

   public Uri GetSomethingFromBar()
   {
        //do the same operation like in middleware
        var foo = RequestHeaderExtractor.GetValue(_httpContext.Request, Constants.FooName);
        var fooEntity = _dataContext
            .Foo
            .Include(x => x.Bar)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Foo == foo);

        return fooEntity.Bar.Something;
   }
}```
````

Comment: Can you show some of the code you used? Mainly middleware (not the main business logic, just structure of the class. constructor methods, etc) and how you used it?

Comment: you can inject scoped classes directly into `InvokeAsync` function